# What are "M" point locations on the NOAA forcecast cone map?

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, weather

I don't think I've ever noticed M before.

H and S are Hurricane and Tropical Storm.

[image]

Comment: The Legend helps... S39-73mph H74-110mph & M >110mph
- M for Major is likely though NASA launched a weather satellite called NOAA-M, later renamed (NOAA)-17(M). A clue maybe?
http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Newsroom/view.php?old=200206249448

Comment: So it was right there in front of me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M must be new this year - I hadn't noticed it before either. From the Forecast Positions legend on the map, it looks like M denotes winds predicted to exceed 110mph at a forecast position. Since 111mph is the lower bound of Category 3 on the Saffir-Simpson Hurricane Scale, my guess is that M stands for "Major Hurricane".

Comment: Major.  Makes sense, although I was hoping for "Monster" or "Mega".

I re-googled and found an alternative map using Google: http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/refresh/graphics_at1+shtml/143812.shtml?gm_track

And it has a legend! http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gifs/forecast_legend_v6.png

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is a 'Major Hurricane'.  Major hurricanes are defined as being of Category 3 or greater.  The wind speeds in the definition of a Category 3 hurricane on this page http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboutgloss.shtml matches the wind speed classes in the legend on the map.